# Generate random string of length n with only m coin flips

Tags: probability, probability-theory

You want to generate a random string of 0s and 1s of length $n$ and are **only** allowed to flip a fair coin $m$ times. The entries should be **pairwise uniform**: ∀ i,j ∈ {1, ... , }, the event $_$ = "the $i$th entry is a 1" has probability 0.5 and $_$, $_$ are independent. How large can $n$ be in terms of $m$?

I understand that if we had $n≤m$ we could just flip the coin $n$ times and generate 1s for Heads and 0s for Tails. But is it possible to have a larger $n$ with $n>m$? Thank you!

Comment: It is not possible, if $n=1$, then $m\leq 0$.

Comment: Since you want the variables to be iid, no. You need to have $2^n$ equally likely possible strings but the $m$ flips give you only $2^m$ distinct outcomes.

Comment: Can we do it if the string of length $2^n$ is only required to be pairwise independent, rather than independent?

Comment: @GEdgar oh, sorry, yes, I edited the post: the entries of the string need to be pairwise independent rather than independent. Do you have a hint for how to solve the problem in that case? Thank you.

Comment: You might use external variables while tossing the coin, for eg. toss the coin onto a chess board, whether it lands on a black or white square can be counted as an additional bit, presumably independent of the head/tail state of the coin...

Comment: @James that is not allowed in my problem, unfortunately

Comment: Example: for $n=3,m=2$ you can do the "pairwise independent" case.

Comment: how about using the m bit as a lookup to choose fron 2^m iid random strings pregenerated
 to be length n? Basically, hash the m string. to length n

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a possible string construction, taking m=5:

Perform 5 coin tosses, with results say $01100$.

1. From the obtained result, take binary sum (no carry) in all possible $\binom{5}{1}=5$ combinations, ie. $01100$.
2. Take binary sum in $\binom{5}{2}=10$ combinations, ie. $11000011110$.
3. Take binary sum in $\binom{5}{3}=10$ combinations, ie $0111100011$.
4. Take binary sum in $\binom{5}{4}=5$ combinations, ie. $00110$.
5. Take binary sum in $\binom{5}{5}=1$ combinations, ie. $0$.

String everything together to make a long string:

$$01100110000111100111100011001100$$

It can be shown that all ${E_i, E_j}$ pairs generated in this way are pairwise independent. This shows $n$ can be exponentially large in terms of $m$:

$$n = \sum_{k=1}^m \binom{m}{k}=2^m-1$$
I do not know if it is possible to achieve a larger value of $n$.